# One thousand independent rolls of a fair die is made.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

> **Question:** One thousand independent rolls of a fair die is made. If the number $6$ appears exactly $200$ times, find the probability that number $5$ appears less than $150$ times. (Use appropriate statistical table)
>
> **Answer:** $0.1762$

Let $p$ be the probability of rolling a 6 on one roll, and $q=1-p$.

Now this is a problem of conditional probability where we have to apply binomial approximation to standard normal distribution since $n \to \infty$ and $p,q < \infty$.

Let $X_1$ be the random variable corresponding to the getting of $6$ and $X_2$ be the random variable corresponding to the getting of $5$.

Now required probability is
$$
P(X_2<150|X_1=200)
=\frac{P((X_2<150 )\ \mathrm{ and }\ (X_1=200))}{P(X_1=200)}
$$
Now the denominator can be easily found but I face problem with the numerator.

How to proceed ?

Comment: An alternative approach might be the probability that number $5$ appears fewer than $150$ times in $1000-200=800$ rolls of a fair five-sided die. I get about $0.17698$

Comment: Let $X$ be the number of $5$s in the remaining $800$ throws, it is binomially distributed with mean $\mu=800/5=160$ and variance $\sigma^2=800(1/5)(4/5)=128$. Can you use the normal approximation to determine $\Pr(X<150)$?

Comment: @molarmass Why not write that in an answer post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case is quite trivial to compute the conditional probability: you made 1000 rolls and you know 200 of those were not a 5. Also, the remaining rolls were picked from the set {1,2,3,4,5}. Hence, it is the same as rolling a 5-sided die 800 times.

$P(X_2 < 150)$ is then approximated by a normal distribution with mean $\mu = 800/5 = 160$ and $\sigma^2 = 800(1/5)(4/5) = 128$. EDIT: As it was pointed out, you should take 0.5 from 150, to account for the continuum approximation from a discrete space.

If you are to use a table, you should now standarize your distribution, which is done by taking the mean from $X_2$ and then dividing by $\sigma$. Hence, what you want to compute is

$$P(X_2 < 150) = \int_{-\infty}^{\frac{149.5-160}{\sqrt(128)}} \frac{1}{2\pi} exp(-\frac{1}{2}x^2)= 0.1762 $$

according to WolframAlpha.

Again, if you are looking on a table, usually they give integrals from $-\infty$ to some positive number. Since you look for the integral from $-\infty$ to -0.928 aprox, which is negative, this is the same as integrating from +0.928 to $+\infty$, or otherwise, 1 minus the probability integrated from $-\infty$ to +0.928.

So look on the table for the closest thing to 0.928, name that $p$ and then the answer is $1-p$.

Comment: You need to do X2 <150.5 , I hope you know why so. Doing that you shall get .17618 which is approximately .1762

Comment: Ah yes, wanted to go too fast. I'm going to change that, thanks.

Comment: I had wrongly typed 150.5 but it should be 149.5 and the integral is from -infinity to -.930 so please update accordingly and its my mistake of doing the typing error. Sorry

Comment: Using one line function in R `pnorm(150.5, mean = 160, sd = sqrt(128))` gives the answer  $0.20054$ and not $0.176$.